# Optimizations for Solr lookup by Id (NoSQL usecase)

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I have a Solr instance with a couple of million nodes. There are regular search usecases I have which work fine, but I have a pretty tight SLA on the lookup usecase, wherein I use Solr like a NoSQL DB and lookup bu 2 different IDs. The unique ID and another field (indexed, ofc). I was performing the lookup query like this:

```
?q=MyID:1234
```

which I realized was bad and started using this instead:

```
?q=*:*&fq=MyID:1234
```

Is there any other optimizations I can do to make sure my lookup is quick(er) ?

Comment: fq is only faster the second time the same fq is given. If your lookup IDs are fairly unique, the first version should be faster.

Comment: well, they are not unique for sure. The cache is defn getting utilized from what I see. I was wondering if I missed anything apart from the above to make lookups faster. Is there anything else I can do ?

Answer (score 0):

If that ID is the unique ID for the record, you could try using [Real Time GET handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RealTime+Get). Beware though that it will give you uncommitted records as well (that's what it is designed for).

Comment: Unique ID is just one of the usecases. We have a lookup usecase for even an indexed field. The numbers I am seeing now (service-lookup-solr->solr->service is around 30ms ! Wondering why its taking so long ! Also, is real time get faster than using fq ?

Comment: 30ms is very long for a simple lookup. Is it QTime or measured time? QTime for trivial lookups are normally around 1-3ms.
If your documents have many and/or large fields, you can try limiting the amount of fields returned (fl=...). If nothing else, that can help you pinpoint the problem.